# Server sends mysql has gone away error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I use comet in my website.. The long polling script returns **"Mysql has gone away"** error often...

I have used **mysqli** extension (object-oriented) to connect php with mysql database

even `php *mysqli -> ping()*` method doesn't fix this problem.

The best part of this is the error did not occur for two months i was using this website with comet 
But now it occurres....

Tips: I changed mysql database's collation to ***utfmb4_unicode_ci*** and charset to ***utbmb4***

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check below thinks in **my.cnf**

```
check that wait_timeout mysql variable in your my.cnf configuration file is large enough.
```

Also check **max_allowed_packet**

```
 set max_allowed_packet = 128M,
```

then restart your MySQL server

Comment: Um using a webhost(000webhost)... so how can i access my.conf?